# Aggregate expression issue with GROUPBY

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to do a simple percentage calculation but no matter what I do I keep ending up with `0` for my field `accuracy`. I've tried casting this as `DOUBLE` as well with no luck. Both inputs generate a number individually so I cannot figure out why I keep getting 0 as a result. I simply want to do (`# of TRUE`/`Records`) for a given month. I suspect the issue here is that I am grouping this by the month but don't know how to resolve.

Do I need to make the counts a subquery for the division or can I do this all in one query?

### Table

```
+------------+-------+----+
| Date       | reg   | id |
+------------+-------+----+
| 2020-05-01 | TRUE  | 1  |
+------------+-------+----+
| 2020-05-02 | TRUE  | 2  |
+------------+-------+----+
| 2020-05-03 | FALSE | 3  |
+------------+-------+----+
| 2020-05-03 | TRUE  | 4  |
+------------+-------+----+
| 2020-05-03 | TRUE  | 5  |
+------------+-------+----+
| 2020-05-04 | FALSE | 6  |
+------------+-------+----+
```

### Query

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(date, 1, 7) as month_year,
    SUM(CASE WHEN reg = FALSE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as error,
    SUM(CASE WHEN reg = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as valid,
    COUNT(reg) as records,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN reg = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(reg), 2) as accuracy
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presto presumably does integer division.  But, you don't need division anyway.  Replace:

```
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN reg = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(reg), 2) as accuracy
```

With:

```
ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN reg = TRUE THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END), 2) as accuracy
```

The `= TRUE` is redundant, but I left it because you have it in your code.